# Converting from epoch date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, epoch

I'm using an API in javascript that retrieves several information of stocks such as open, high, low and closing prices as well as date. However,this date is in epoch format (date: 1627047000, for example). How could I format this in this code so that I could have something like DD/MM/YYYY?

```
const yahooStockAPI  = require('yahoo-stock-api');

async function main()  {
    const startDate = new Date('07/01/2021');
    const endDate = new Date('07/25/2021');
    console.log(await yahooStockAPI.getHistoricalPrices(startDate, endDate, 'AMZN', '1d'));
}
main();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Parsing timestamps with the built–in parser as in `new Date('07/01/2021')` is strongly discouraged, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). Much better to give the parts directly to the constructor: `new Date(2021, 6, 1)` for 2021-07-01.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply the epoch value times 1000 to convert to milliseconds (which is what javascript dates are based on) and pass to a new Date object then you can use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) to return format you want

```js
const obj = {date: 1627047000};

const date = new Date(obj.date * 1000); 

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date));
```